# Refer to User (a Foreign Key) to fill in argument's default value

Tags: django

I have a structure similar to grocery shopping baskets. The user can have many baskets, and inside each basket, there are several bags holding fruits or other types of items.

I categorize each bag by item and color, that is, each bag only holds the same type of item with the same color. I keep track of how many of that item are there. So a bag may be: "3 Red Apples", another "60 Red Cherries"

Each user may choose a favorite color, and this is stored as a `UserOption` entry. I chose not to modify the built-in `User` model.

I want to simplify a function for computing the total number (quantity) of items of a given color in the desired basket. When no color is given, the favorite color is picked.

I have a working function, called `get_total_default_none`, that pulls the favorite color inside the function, but my question is:

**Is it possible to retrieve the user's favorite color directly as the parameter's default (in the function signature), instead of running the query inside the function?**

I think this (working) approach is ugly, needing to use the `None` as default, and then checking the `UserOption`.

When I try referring to `user` (as shown immediately below), and run the shell, I get `django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.`. I also tried (following advice in other questions) replacing `User` with `django.conf.settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`. These did not work.

```
def get_total(self, color=UserOption.objects.filter(user=user)[0].favorite_color):
    # ...
    pass
```

My models are:

```
class Color(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class UserOption(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    favorite_color = models.ForeignKey(Color, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Basket(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    # THIS FUNCTION WORKS BUT IS UGLY, I THINK
    def get_total_default_none(self, color=None):
        if color is None:
            try:
                color = UserOption.objects.filter(user=self.user)[0].favorite_color
            except IndexError:
                print("Could not retrieve user's favorite_color")

        total = 0
        bags = self.bag_set.filter(color=color)
        for bag in bags:
            total += bag.quantity
        return total

    # I HOPE TO GET SOMETHING LIKE THIS WORKING:    
    def get_total(self, color=UserOption.objects.filter(user=user)[0].favorite_color):
        # use code similar to above
        pass

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Bag(models.Model):
    user      = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    color     = models.ForeignKey(Color, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity  = models.IntegerField()
    basket    = models.ForeignKey(Basket, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You could access the relationship directly.

```
def get_total(self):
    color = self.user.useroption_set.first()
    if color:
        color = color.favorite_color
```

`first()` will return None if the user has no UserOptions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; my question was perhaps unclear so I edited it. I am assuming the UserOption will be set, and am trying to read it in the function's signature, to set it as the default parameter, or allow the caller to provide an alternate color.

Comment: Trying `def get_total(self, color=user.useroption_set.first().favorite_color):` will give me a `AttributeError: 'ForeignKey' object has no attribute 'useroption_set'` I am starting to think it is impossible to do what I want.